# Draw acos(1/x) in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to draw the graph of y=acos(1/x) using TIKZ. I don't want pgfplot nor do I want pstricks. I want to do it strictly in TIKZ. Here is my attempt. I want to eventually draw on the domain [1,4], but for the moment I am using [1,1.1], otherwise you can't see the rest of my plot.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->](-4,0)--(4,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw [->](0,0)--(0,pi) node[above]{$y$}; 
\draw[red,dashed] (-4,pi/2)--(4,pi/2);
\foreach \x in {-3,-2,-1,1,2,3} \draw (\x,-3pt)--(\x,3pt);
\draw (-3,0) node[below]{$-3$};
\draw (3,0) node[below]{$3$};
\foreach \y in {pi/2,pi} \draw (-3pt,\y)--(3pt,\y);
\draw (0,pi/2) node[left]{$\dfrac{\pi}{2}$};
\draw (0,pi) node[left]{$\pi$};
\draw[thick,blue,->] plot [domain=1:1.1] (\x,{acos(1.0/\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

The resulting image.

[image]

I don't know what is happening here, because the plot should approach the horizontal asymptote $y=\pi/2$.

Any thoughts?

Comment: My impression is that `acos` returns degrees.

Answer (score 9):

The `acos` function returns the value in degrees; you have to convert to radians.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->](-4,0)--(4,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw [->](0,0)--(0,pi) node[above]{$y$};
\draw[red,dashed] (-4,pi/2)--(4,pi/2);
\foreach \x in {-3,-2,-1,1,2,3} \draw (\x,-3pt)--(\x,3pt);
\draw (-3,0) node[below]{$-3$};
\draw (3,0) node[below]{$3$};
\foreach \y in {pi/2,pi} \draw (-3pt,\y)--(3pt,\y);
\draw (0,pi/2) node[left]{$\dfrac{\pi}{2}$};
\draw (0,pi) node[left]{$\pi$};
\draw[thick,blue,->] plot [domain=1:5,samples=200] (\x,{rad(acos(1.0/\x))});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course! Beautiful answer. Going to be very helpful as I write out the solutions for my students' midterm. Thanks.