# Function won't plot ("dimension too large" error)

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

I want to plot this function (excuse me, I don't know how to write equations on this forum):

f(x) = -2*arccos(0.5*e^(ln(4)/x) -1) + pi

When I enter the code (shown below) in `pgfplots`, I get a error that says "dimension too large". I've tried to put `x`, and the whole inside of the `arccos` in `deg()`, I've restricted the `y` domain to `2:8` (so it is continues), but nothing seems to work. The only way I don't get an error, is by removing the `deg()`. However, then I get an empty grid where no function is shown. Does anyone know how to get this function plotted?

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3, transform shape]
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-8, xmax=8, ymin=-4, ymax=4, restrict y to domain=-8:1, axis x line=center, axis y line=center]
    \addplot[color=blue, samples=100, domain=2:8]
    {-2*acos( 0.5*e^(ln(4)/x) -1 )+pi};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \centering
\label{fig:thetafunction}
\end{figure}
```

[Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9iojra6fe1) you can find how the plot should look like.

Comment: In your definition of `f(x)` I see an exponential function, but in the code below you write `2^`... Is this a typo or which function are you exactly trying to plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what you exactly wanted to do with the `y`domain, since your function only depends on `x`. The problem was that the `acos` functions returns the answer in degrees, but you want it in rad (if I understood you correctly). See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237397/draw-acos1-x-in-tikz) answer. Also, I'm not sure if one could handle the domain problem better, but since your `x` is in the denominator, you have a problem at `x=0`. I just split the domain into two parts, feel free to change the bounds as necessary for you.  Hope this works for you.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot[color=blue, samples=100, domain=1:8]
    {pi -2.0 * rad(acos(0.5 * exp(ln(4.0)/x) - 1.0))};
    \addplot[color=red, samples=100, domain=-8:-0.1]
    {pi -2.0 * rad(acos(0.5 * exp(ln(4.0)/x) - 1.0))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, thanks! A friend helped me with other graphs, and in those graphs restricting the y domein worked, but it doesn't really make sense in this case, indeed.